# Read File to Print to Screen

Tags: java, readfile

I have a file Inventory.txt that I am trying to print to the screen. Each line from the file goes into an object array. My code compiles with no errors but when I run it, nothing prints nothing to the screen. Im using Mac and TextEdit/Terminal.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*; 

public class VendingMachineSimulator
{
    to be imported
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException 
    {

        File InventoryFile = new File("Inventory.txt");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(InventoryFile);

        //This code block will count the number of lines(products) are in the text file
        int counter = 0;
        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }

        Inventory[] InventoryObject = new Inventory[counter];
        String line = "";


        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            String[] ProductArray = line.split("-");

            InventoryObject[i] = new Inventory(Integer.valueOf(ProductArray[0]), ProductArray[1], ProductArray[2], 
                                               ProductArray[3],Double.valueOf(ProductArray[4]), ProductArray[5], 
                                               Integer.valueOf(ProductArray[6]));
        } 

        for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        {
            System.out.println();
            InventoryObject[i].PrintInventory();
        } 


    }

    public static void PrintMenu()
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Display Inventory: <1>");
        System.out.println("Display Currency:  <2>");
        System.out.println("Purchase Item:     <3>");
        System.out.println("Exit:              <4>");
        System.out.println();
    }


}

class Inventory
{
    private int ID;
    private String Type;
    private String Name;
    private String PriceText;
    private double Cost;
    private String QuantityText;
    private int StockAmount;

    //Constructor method. values passed to it from the main method. 
    public Inventory(int ID, String Type, String Name, String PriceText, double Cost, String QuantityText, int StockAmount) 
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.PriceText = PriceText;
        this.Cost = Cost;
        this.QuantityText = QuantityText;
        this.StockAmount = StockAmount;
    }

    public void setID(int ID)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
    }

    public void setType(String Type)
    {
        this.Type = Type;
    }

    public void setName(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public void setPriceText(String PriceText)
    {
        this.PriceText = PriceText;
    }

    public void setCost(double Cost)
    {
        this.Cost = Cost;
    }

    public void setQuantityText(String QuantityText)
    {
        this.QuantityText = QuantityText;
    }

    public void setStockAmount(int StockAmount)
    {
        this.StockAmount = StockAmount;
    }

    public int getID()
    {
        return ID;
    }

    public String getType()
    {
        return Type;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public String getPriceText()
    {
        return PriceText;
    }

    public double getCost()
    {
        return Cost;
    }

    public String getQuantityText()
    {
        return QuantityText;
    }

    public int getStockAmount()
    {
        return StockAmount;
    }

    public void PrintInventory()
    {
        System.out.println(ID + " " + Type + " " + Name + " " + PriceText
                           + " " + Cost + " " + QuantityText + " " + StockAmount);
    }




}
```

Comment: You set line to "" and never change it?

Answer (score 0):

You never read a line, you only count them:

```
while (input.hasNextLine())
{
    counter = counter + 1;
}
```

You have to place `line = input.readLine();` inside this loop somewhere and change your logic accordingly, otherwise, it will always stay in the while loop. Think about when you would need to update or read the counter.

Answer (score 0):

This is an endless loop. If there is text in the file, the input has a next line.
Since that line isn't read in the loop, `input.hasNextLine()` is always true.

```
        while (input.hasNextLine())
        {
            counter = counter + 1;
        }
```

You should rather use a List to read the Objects, that way you don't need to know the size initially.

Answer (score 0):

You are blocking the input from the `Inventory.txt` file in you `while` loop. You are only checking if a next line exists without actually reading the next line. So you're going to an infinite loop here:

```
    int counter = 0;
    while (input.hasNextLine())
    {
        counter = counter + 1;
    }
```

You need to call this at some point inside your whilte loop:

```
input.nextLine();
```

Tip: You can consolidate all the actions that you are performing inside this `while` loop. You probably don't need as many loops:

1. Assigning to `line`; Declare `line` before the `while` loop.
2. Splitting line into `ProductArray`. This will be `line.split` assigned to `ProductArray`.
3. Creating the new Inventory object. You may not need an array of Inventory Objects. Simply create one using the `ProductArray` variable.
4. Printing the inventory. Simply call the `PrintInventory` method on the the object created in step 3.

---

Hope this helps!

Comment: Having some trouble with your tip. I set the 'line' to be a string array such that it could be split into 'ProductArray' but I am getting the 'ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'.

Comment: I wasn't able to get everything consolidated into the single while loop to work. I created a new Scanner and assigned line to it and then assigned that to ProductArray and initialized the InventoryObject array in a for loop. Not as efficient, but it works

Answer (score 0):

1. You can remove the first while loop as its infinite loop.
2. Change the for loop to a while loop and do itererate as long as you have a next line and within the loop read the nextline and assign to line string and change the inventoryObject to an ArrayList and add items.

This should ideally resolve the issue.

Comment: For this assignment, I cannot use ArrayList...I have to manually create the array